# Why is there a SQLiteException: near "AND". while every thing is Right?

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my Logcat Error line:

```
03-31 17:51:53.578: E/AndroidRuntime(13202):
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near
"AND": syntax error: , while compiling: 

SELECT saudamst.date AS date, saudamst.contract_no AS cno, accmst1.name AS sname,      accmst2.name AS bname, itemmst.name AS item, saudamst.quantity,saudamst.rate 
FROM saudamst join accmst accmst1 on (saudamst.seller_name = accmst1.vou) join accmst accmst2 on (saudamst.buyer_name = accmst2.vou) join itemmst on (saudamst.item = itemmst.vou)
WHERE date > ? AND date < ? AND cno=? AND sname LIKE ?% AND bname LIKE ?% AND item LIKE ?% 
ORDER BY contract_no DESC
```

Can you trace the Error??

Comment: ok I am updating my question..

Comment: The code is included in the trace. I formatted it a bit to make it clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE ?%` is not syntactically correct. Use `LIKE ? || '%'` to use both `?` placeholders and `%` literal.

`||` is the string concatenation operator in SQL.

Comment: what the "||" in " LIKE ? || '% " stand for?

Comment: I thought i had missed the single quote '. should I use '?'% or '?%'

Comment: Neither. Literal placeholder `?` should not be quoted, string literals such as `%` need to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this:

```
"anything LIKE '%"
```